# Who detonated the car bomb in the finale of "The Falcon and the Winter Soldier"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In the final episode of *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, "One World, One People",

> some (all?) of the remaining Flag Smashers are loaded into an armoured truck to be transported to the Raft. One of the officers says *"One World, One People"* to them indicating an escape plan is on the cards.

However, almost as soon as the trucks set off they are blown up. The camera then pans over to an old man in a car putting what is likely the detonator into his pocket.

Who detonated the bomb to blow up the armoured truck?

Comment: Yikes.  Question, Title and Answer need some *serious SPOILER tags*...  This is in HNQ.

Comment: The fact that a car bomb exists isn't much of a spoiler in modern television. The actually spoiler-y part is properly hidden in the question; and there's enough context in the title that a HNQ visitor can decide not to click if they don't want to be spoiled

Comment: @Cireo If you view an answer about a question on the finale of a season that’s your own fault. However, feel free to suggest an edit to the question of you feel there are spoilers there.

Comment: @Roddy: maybe the existence of a car bomb over the entire storyline isn't necessarily a spoiler, at least not in an action/adventure story. But the fact that a car bomb exists in the finale sure seems like a spoiler to me. I disagree that the title itself is not in need of repair.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do not see any angle where this is giving away information in a context that can alter the viewing expierience. Especially as this is not even the first car bomb in the series, that deals with a group of urban "terrorists".

Comment: The answer is rather obvious, IMHO. Even if you forgot or missed the episode where the character first appeared, the succeeding scenes make it rather obvious that the character is allied to Zemo, and the only character introduced so far that is allied to Zemo, is his butler.

Comment: @galacticninja If you haven't noticed already this was a self answer. Sometimes obvious but not necessarily so questions are quite good to try and keep activity alive in a tag. For such a popular work it has had very few questions on it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Zemo's Butler (Oeznik) did it.

[image: Oeznik sat in his car pocketing the detonator, s01e06]
[image: Oeznik front of the plane, s01e03]
Notice the white gloves.
[image: Oeznik profile picture, s01e03]

Comment: Of course the butler did it.

Answer (score 28):

#### Oeznik, Zemo's butler

This person is Oeznik, Zemo's butler, that we had previously met in episode 3, "Power Broker", when Zemo takes them to his private plane. Compare the images below from the two scenes:

[image: Oeznik welcomes Zemo onboard the plane as Sam and Bucky follow on behind]

[image: Oeznik sat in his car watching the bomb go off as he puts the detonator away into his coat pocket]

It is also hinted at a that Zemo is behind it even if you don't recognise the character. Right after the close on Oeznik it cuts to a view of Zemo in his cell at the Raft indicating he is somehow related to the incident. We also have Valentina's comments to Olivia, Walker's wife, on the incident. She jokes she was behind it but it seems to be just that, a joke.

> **Valentina:** Oh! Ooh. Hey, Walker, check your phone. Looks like our friend, Zemo, kinda got the last laugh, right?
>
> **Olivia:** Wow.
>
> **Valentina:** Couldn’t have worked better if I planned it myself. Oh. Well, maybe I did. No, I’m kidding, I didn’t. Or did I? Anyway, it’s gonna save people a lot of paperwork and a lot of redacting and a lot of shredding.
>
> <sub>*The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, Season 1 Episode 6, "One World, One People"</sub>

Lastly, it of course makes sense that Zemo is behind it given his devotion to getting rid of the super soldiers and an Avengers-like team. Zemo's mission throughout the season is to destroy the super soldiers and the serum's creator. It makes sense that he contacted Oeznik at some point to help put an end to them should he be captured.

> **Zemo:** I spent years hunting people HYDRA recruited to recreate the serum. Because once it's out there, someone can create an army of people... like the Avengers. I ended the Winter Soldier program once before. I have no intention to leave my work unfinished.
>
> <sub>*The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, Season 1 Episode 3, "Power Broker"</sub>

Comment: Hmm .. There are at least 3 out people out there who have received there serum that Zemo hasn't terminated.  Bucky, John Walker and Isaiah Bradley.  So are they at risk given that Oeznik seems to be running freely around carrying out Zemo's work?

Comment: @PeterM Zemo tells Bucky he’s decided not to kill him before the Wakandans take him away. There’s no indication he knows of Isaiah. He might not necessarily know about Walker either but that’s popes  to be explored later on should Marvel decide to.

Comment: @PeterM Zemo has nothing against Bucky (as directly stated in Civil War and this series) - his motivation to stop supersoldiers hinges on ideology (hotel scene ep4) and desire of said soldiers to be superior. Volunteers (like the Flagsmashers or the Hydra unit from Civil War) are the reason he does what he does. Bucky and Isaiah never volunteered for the serum, and never took pride in their resulting status, so Zemo doesn't see them as targets. Walker is a different matter, we'll see.